# Issue : Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column Sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

My table structure as follow

```
ID   JID     EntryDate   RefundDate Comments     Refund ActionBy
---- ------- ----------- ---------- ------------ ------ --------
3    41986   2013-12-17  12/24/2013 Cancel       0      Matt
4    41986   2013-12-17  12/25/2013 done         1      Kelly
5    41986   2013-12-17  12/24/2013 no           0      Smith
```

i want this type of output after issuing sql

```
JID     EntryDate   RefundDate Comments     Refund ActionBy
------- ----------- ---------- ------------ ------ ---------
 41986
     2013-12-17  12/24/2013 Cancel       0      Matt
     2013-12-17  12/25/2013 done         1      Kelly
     2013-12-17  12/24/2013 no           0      Smith

 41987
     2013-12-17  12/24/2013 Cancel       0      Mosa
     2013-12-17  12/25/2013 done         1      Mike
     2013-12-17  12/24/2013 no           0      Jen


 41988
     2013-12-17  12/24/2013 Cancel       0      Ruby
     2013-12-17  12/25/2013 done         1      Kelly
     2013-12-17  12/24/2013 no           0      Simon
```

just to get the above output i issued this sql as follows

```
;WITH  Hierarchy AS
(
    --  Anchor
    SELECT TOP 1  JID
            ,NULL EntryDate
            ,NULL RefundDate
            ,NULL Comments
            ,NULL Refund
            ,NULL ActionBy
            ,nLevel = 1
    FROM refundrequested

    UNION ALL
    --  Recursive query
    SELECT   E.JID
            ,E.EntryDate
            ,E.RefundDate
            ,E.Comments
            ,E.Refund
            ,E.ActionBy
            ,H.nLevel+1

    FROM refundrequested   E
    JOIN Hierarchy  H ON E.JID = H.JID
)

SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy

ORDER BY JID, nLevel
```

### UPDATE

```
;WITH  Hierarchy AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT  JID
            ,CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) EntryDate
            ,CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) RefundDate
            ,CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(MAX)) Comments
            ,CAST(NULL AS BIT) Refund
            ,CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(30)) ActionBy
            ,nLevel = 1
    FROM refundrequested
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   CAST(NULL AS INT) JID
            ,E.EntryDate
            ,E.RefundDate
            ,E.Comments
            ,E.Refund
            ,E.ActionBy
            ,H.nLevel+1

    FROM refundrequested   E
    JOIN Hierarchy  H ON E.JID = H.JID
)

SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy
ORDER BY JID DESC, nLevel
```

now getting this error  **The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.**

how to fix the above error and what is the meaning of the error....not clear.

Comment: You can simple cast the columns in the anchor query to the corresponding type in the recursive query, since the columns in `UNION ALL` have to match like [**this**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee5fc/7), but your query is not terminated.

Comment: can i cast NULL to varchar or datetime?

Comment: Yes, it is working fine in the sql fiddle demo link I put in my comment. Have you seen it?

Comment: still error is there after casting the null.

Comment: Error as follows : Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "RefundDate" of recursive query "Hierarchy".

Comment: The error is not in the casting, the error is that the query still working and reaches the maximum number of iteration, you have to limit it.

Comment: You have to cast all the columns, like what I did here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee5fc/7

Comment: what to write for limit and where?

Comment: The MAXRECURSION query hint limits the number of times the CTE will recurse.  This limit is by default set to 100.  If you loop more times than that, you get an error.  Are you sure you haven't written an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

explain your output.i am not getting nlevel part.what decide nlevel and how long it can go ?

```
;WITH  Hierarchy AS
(
    --  Anchor
    SELECT TOP 1  JID
            ,cast(NULL as date) EntryDate
            ,cast(NULL as date) RefundDate
            ,cast(NULL as varchar(10)) Comments
            ,cast(NULL as bit) Refund
            ,cast(NULL as varchar(10)) ActionBy
            ,nLevel = 1
    FROM @t

    UNION ALL
    --  Recursive query
    SELECT   E.JID
            ,E.EntryDate
            ,E.RefundDate
            ,E.Comments
            ,E.Refund
            ,E.ActionBy
            ,H.nLevel+1

    FROM @t   E
    JOIN Hierarchy  H ON E.JID = H.JID where h.nLevel<=3
)

select * from Hierarchy
```

Comment: now getting this error : The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: what is The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted means ??

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH  Hierarchy AS
(
(SELECT  JID E,EntryDate, RefundDate, Comments
, Refundrequested, ActionBy FROM refundrequested)
UNION ALL
SELECT E +1,EntryDate,RefundDate,Comments,Refund,ActionBy FROM  Hierarchy  H 
Where E<41988)
SELECT E AS JID,EntryDate, RefundDate, Comments
, Refund,CASE WHEN E=41987 AND comments='cancel' THEN 'Mosa'
 WHEN E=41987 AND comments='cancel' THEN 'Mosa'
 WHEN E=41987 AND comments='done' THEN 'Mike'
 WHEN E=41987 AND comments='no' THEN 'Jen'
 WHEN E=41988 AND comments='cancel' THEN 'Ruby'
 WHEN E=41988 AND comments='done' THEN 'Kelly'
 WHEN E=41988 AND comments='no' THEN 'Simon' 
 ELSE ActionBy END AS ActionBy FROM Hierarchy 
 Order BY E ,Comments
```